# I'm not able to transfer JSON data to Database

Tags: android, json, android-sqlite

I've written a routine to transfer data from JSON to SQLite database in Android,but for some reason,its not getting transferred,am i missing something?
This is my OncreateInstance

```
 try
    {
        JSONObject jsonObject=new JSONObject(ParsingDta);
        JSONArray jsonArray= jsonObject.getJSONArray(ParsingDta);
        for(int i=0;i<jsonArray.length();i++)
        {
            JSONObject jsonObject1=jsonArray.getJSONObject(i);
            String rtrname=jsonObject1.getString("rtrname").toString();
            String ctgname=jsonObject1.getString("ctgname").toString();
            String rtrphoneno=jsonObject1.getString("rtrphoneno").toString();

            str+="\n Retailers"+i+ "\n rtrname:"+rtrname+"\n ctgname:"+ctgname+"\n rtrphoneno:" +rtrphoneno+"\n";
            boolean isInserted = database.insertData(rtrname,ctgname,rtrphoneno);
            if (isInserted == true)
                Toast.makeText(MainActivity.this, "Data Inserted", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
            else
                Toast.makeText(MainActivity.this, "Data not Inserted", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
            //textView1.setText(str);
        }
    }
    catch(JSONException e)
    {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
    Cursor res =database.getAllData();
    if (res.getCount() == 0) {
        //show message
        showMessage("Error", "Nothing found");
        return;
    }
```

This is my ParsingData contents

```
String ParsingDta= "{\"Retailers\":[{\"billedret\":0,\"class\":\"com.enteleki.sfa.botree.RetailerSummary\",\"ctgcode\":\"G003\",\"ctgname\":\"Cosmetic\",\"distcode\":\"DL/0004\",\"mktid\":6,\"rtradd1\":\"D 12/225 Sec 7\",\"rtrclassid\":12,\"rtrcode\":\"RE0012\",\"rtrid\":5,\"rtrname\":\"Aggarwal Cosmetics\",\"rtrphoneno\":\"27049003\",\"srpcde\":\"2\",\"valueclasscode\":\"CL004\",\"valueclassname\":\"D\"}]}";
```

And Following is my DataBaseHelperClass for insertData function

```
 public boolean insertData(String rtrname, String ctgname,String rtrphoneno) {
    SQLiteDatabase db = this.getWritableDatabase();
    ContentValues contentValues = new ContentValues();

    //contentValues.put(COL_2,rtrphoneno);
    contentValues.put(COL_2,rtrname);
    contentValues.put(COL_3, ctgname);
    contentValues.put(COL_4, rtrphoneno);
    long result = db.insert(TABLE_NAME,null ,contentValues);
    if(result == -1)
        return false;
    else
        return true;
}
```

This has been driving me nuts,help would be deeply appreciated

Comment: post your json response also

Comment: Some more information is needed to find out where the problem is. For example, do you see one of the Toasts? Is there an error in logcat?

Comment: I don't see the toast,there's no error in the logcat as well

Comment: @VivekMishra JSON response,you mean the JSON data ??

Comment: yes post it in your question as it may be possible that you are parsing it wrong

Comment: @VivekMishra The parsing method is also included,if you want the data that is being parsed,then i can add that

Comment: I would say you don't get any elements in your parsed array. Can/would you print/toast out the length of the array. You perform a ` jsonObject.getJSONArray(ParsingDta)` on a text that contains an object. Perhaps that's the problem.

Comment: why all these extra slashes in response?? First remove them

Comment: @Vivek Mishra what you mean ??

Comment: @PaulPeter So the Data format isn't right ?? I'm new to JSON..could you show me how the data can be moulded ??

Comment: Thinking about it again, I'm sure the `getJSONArray` is the problem. Try ... ` jsonObject.getJSONArray("Retailers")`.

Comment: As far as I see your JSON is valid. I think you passed the wrong argument to the method  `getJSONArray`.

Comment: Hmm..what if I remove the "Retailers" thingy and run it instead ?? Then that should make it work right ?? @PeterPaul

Comment: Sorry I'm at work I can not aswer at once. I don't know  your JSON parser very well. I expect the call `JSONArray jsonArray=  new JSONArray(ParsingDta);` would work, if you have only an array `[...]` defined in the JSON String .

Comment: @PeterPaulKiefer Yes it's just a single array,it's OK take your time and let me know if you find the cause

Comment: Give All .java file..if possible

Comment: @VishalPatolia There's only two Java file,one is the above main activity one and another is that DBHelper, honestly I've included the main things of both the .java

Comment: @Venky give a DBHelper file because i see what you write in DBHelper file and give best solution.

Comment: @VishalPatoliaI'm unable to edit anymore,but its just to create Database and make it writable and also make table,that part is fine,since i can see the database created and also the table name